# How to measure network performances?

Tags: android, performance, networking, connection

I am trying to create an app that switches between network interfaces (wifi,3G).and measures latency, bandwith, ... etc by clicking on a button.

- measuring the quality of connection (debit, bandwith, latency, jitter, loss rate, ...)

I've started the app:

```
public class myapp extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView TR; //latency text view 
Button ID_Collect;   //button 
long starttime, endtime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myapp);

    ID_Collect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ID_Collect);
    TR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID_TR);

    ID_Collect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (executeCommand()) {

                TR.setText(String.valueOf(endtime-starttime));

               //TR.setText("success");

            } else {
                TR.setText(" Failure");
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean executeCommand() {
    System.out.println("executeCommand");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
       starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Process mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
       endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Debit=(8)/(endtime-starttime);
        //System.out.println(" mExitValue "+mExitValue);
        if (mExitValue == 0) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" Exception:" + ignore);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" Exception:" + e);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Maybe you have experience about that and you would like to share it?

Comment: For what protocols? I see you are running ping, but that only measures for ICMP, and ICMP results are probably very different than TCP or UDP results.

Comment: I've used the ping just for the test of latency

Comment: That only tests for ICMP latency, which has no relationship to the latency of other protocols. ICMP is a low-priority protocol, and it is more likely to be routed differently, and placed in low-priority queues when there is congestion. Also, you idea of the test is only goo for one destination. All your tests only reveal those parameters for one destination, but could be wildly different if tested to a different destination.

Comment: oh ok thanks.but i m confused what to do about it

Comment: It seems like you are trying to recreate IP SLA: "_IP SLAs continuously collect data about such things as response times, latency, jitter and packet loss._" The problem is that the results are only good from one source to one destination, per protocol. The results can vary by protocol and destination. This is a tool we use, and we use it to check for particular protocols between particular endpoints.

Comment: That's ok.i'll use the same destination.it'snt not important for my work.is there any library that mesures   them.